# How to declare iterator variable as private member variable?

Tags: c++, iterator

Say I want to declare some private class member variables in a class for a doubly linked list and am trying to do something like:

```
DoublyLinkedList<ShippingStatus> package;
DoublyLinkedListIterator<ShippingStatus> ship(&package);
```

I realize that the second line is not possible, but is there any way to declare the `ship` variable by passing in the linked list values as reference? I have done the second line within other functions successfully, but this would mean `ship` would be reset each time these functions are called, and I want the position of my iterator saved "globally" as the program runs. This is what the constructor for the iterator class looks like

```
DoublyLinkedListIterator(DoublyLinkedList<ELT>* list) {
    assert(nullptr != list);
    _location = list->_header->next();
}
```

I can provide any further functions if needed.

Comment: No you don't. Every client that requests an iterator must get its own instance. You are making a design mistake here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could use member initializer list:

```
template <typename ShippingStatus>
class MyClass
{
    DoublyLinkedList<ShippingStatus> package;
    DoublyLinkedListIterator<ShippingStatus> ship;
public:
    MyClass(DoublyLinkedList<ShippingStatus> package) : package{ package }, ship{ &(this->package) } {}
};
```